# Evaluate $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\sin^{-1} (\frac{\cos^{-1} x+\cos^{-1} x^{2}}{\pi })$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

> Evaluate 
>   $$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\sin^{-1} (\frac{\cos^{-1} x+\cos^{-1} x^{2}}{\pi })$$

I tried it by direct substitution

$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\sin^{-1} (\frac{\cos^{-1} x+\cos^{-1} x^{2}}{\pi })$$
$$=\sin^{-1} (\frac{\cos^{-1} 0+\cos^{-1} 0^{2}}{\pi })$$
$$=\sin^{-1} (\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}} {\pi })$$
$$=\sin^{-1} (\frac{\pi}{\pi })= \sin^{-1} 1= \frac{\pi}{2}$$

But my book says limit doesn't exist.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The problem is that when $x<0$, then $\frac{\cos^{-1}(x)+\cos^{-1}(x^2)}{\pi}>1$, so you can't take $\sin^{-1}$ at that point.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\arccos$ is continuous at $x=0$, it's domain is $[-1,1]$ and is continuous within its domain.  $\arcsin$ near the boundary of its domain is more troubling, however.

Comment: Whoops, you are all right. Duh.

Comment: It still means the question needs to be updated to express $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Your comment could probably serve as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x<0$, the inside function $\frac{\cos^{-1}(x)+\cos^{-1}(x^2)}{\pi}$ is greater than 1.  For example, when $x=-.1$, the value the numerator is approximately $3.23176$ (and the entire fraction has value approximately $1.0287$).  Since $\sin^{-1}$ is not defined for values greater than 1, there is no limit from the left.  Hence, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Even if this could be the only reasonable answer, I would like to say that the limit exists, and it is actually $\frac{\pi}{2}$. But this is just a matter of definition of limit. Since the domain of the function is something like $[0, a)$, this limit has to be implicitly considered as a right limit.

Comment: @Crostul Sure, you can define a limit as the "best limit that can exist," but the OP stated that the intended solution was that the limit didn't exist, so the problem was implicitly asking for the standard definition of the limit (that both the left and right limits exist)